# Не работает gradient

Tags: android-sdk, android

У меня есть `drawable` файл, который я ставлю, как `background` для кнопки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

В нем я использую `gradient`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="@color/gray"
            android:startColor="@color/dark_gray" />
    </shape>
</gradient>
```

Без использования `gradient` все работало, но теперь, при попытке установить `background` для кнопки через `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button2)`, приложение вылетает с сообщением "Приложение остановлено". Что я не так сделал в `gradient` или еще где-то?

P.S. Цвета назначены правильно и `drawable` файл, без использования `gradient` тоже прекрасно работал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то Вы лишнего намудрили, уберите внешний `gradient`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <gradient
         android:angle="270"
         android:endColor="@color/gray"
         android:startColor="@color/dark_gray">
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Через 7 минут приму ответ, пишет что "рано" :). Все заработало! Ну... Заработать не заработало, ничего не происходит, а вот ошибку уже не выдает :D.

Comment: @bukashka101 ну так а если в `shape` засунуть `android:shape="rectangle"` к примеру

Comment: Я немного не понимаю, как это все работает, я просто скопировал код со stackoverflow. Но, как ни странно, я случайно закрасил всю кнопку и вышло красивее, чем я хD. Однако, разобраться в этой штуке мне не помешает. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Не помогло, эффект тот же.

Comment: @bukashka101 ну а если добавить <solid android:color="#FFBBAADD" /> что то поменяется?

Comment: Подождите часик. Я тут поставил Activity на весь экран и у меня все layout файлы искривились..